# python 3.11: debugger not working properly anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, version

So I have just installed python version 3.11 and changed my python interpreter in pycharm and the code runs properly now after I reinstalled the packages to my new venv.

but when i debug my code I keep getting a long list of warnings and I have no idea how to fix it:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pydev debugger: CRITICAL WARNING: This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)
pydev debugger: The debugger may still function, but it will work slower and may miss breakpoints.
pydev debugger: Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connected to pydev debugger (build 221.5080.212)
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen codecs>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen importlib._bootstrap>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen zipimport>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen ntpath>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen genericpath>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen os>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen _collections_abc>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <string>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen abc>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <__array_function__ internals>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen io>
```

I installed it for all users to *C:\Program Files* if that helps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Should be fixed in PyCharm 2022.3 (ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56939/CRITICAL-WARNING-error-debugging-Python-311-code).

Early Access Preview version is already available https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to have this error with fastApi you can start it with disabled reload and breakpoints will work again

```
 uvicorn.run("bootstrap:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, reload=False)
```

Updating pycharm or downgrading python to 3.10 also works

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error came up simply for calling a function incorrectly. I had parameters that were referring to one another.
`funct(my_array, my_array[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading Python is also an option. This is especially easy and fast to test creating new Anaconda environment.
Had this error under 3.12, but not under 3.10 PyCharm interpreter.