# Pycharm debugger is broken for python 3.11 on multithreading

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I am using Pycharm professional (latest version 2022.3.3, built on March 10, 2023)
I get the
`pydev debugger: bytes arguments were passed to a new process creation function. Breakpoints may not work correctly.` warning and `all` the breakpoints are skipped.

I saw there was a solution reported here: [python 3.11: debugger not working properly anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74359505/python-3-11-debugger-not-working-properly-anymore)
BUT... it's not a solution for me.
I think it might be because I am working with the code that heavily relies on multithreading.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please don't forget to upvote and [accept it by clicking the green check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to the latest stable version (2023.1.3 atm). It was fixed ([corresponding ticket in PyCharm's issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-57217/Breakpoints-are-ignored-with-Python-3.11-bytes-arguments-were-passed-to-a-new-process-creation-function)).